# Copy files with .pdb extension from source folder to target folder leaving out files from certain folder in source directory

Tags: c#, vbscript

I need to copy all .pdb files from my source folder to target folder but the problem is pdbs with same name are present in two different folders in source directory one  being 64 bit and other being 32 bit. So if I directly do a search and copy then some of my pdbs will be overwritten and I will get only one version of the file. How can I make it work ?

Comment: If this is part of a build process (as it sounds) you should let msbuild handle this and configure your project(s) and solution accordingly. You'll have to add more details on the structure and the actual problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Well i want to copy all my pdbs to the lib folder .We have both 64 bit and 32 bit verisions of certain dlls and I need to copy pdbs for both the dlls  to my lib folder . I can create an x64 folder for the 64 bit pdbs in my lib folder the real problem is copying both the pdbs in their respective locations i.e. in lib and lib\x64 folders respectively

Comment: Also my 64 bit pdbs are in paths whose pathname contains x64 . So what I am trying to do is copy pdbs that are in these paths to my lib\x64 folder and rest of the pdbs in lib folder. Hope this makes things clearer

Comment: Maybe your task could be easier solved using Robocopy instead of vbscript - it's quite useful for mirroring folder structures (x64 folder to x64 folder) and accepting exclude lists (leaving out certain files). I had hoped you would describe the bigger picture because I believe your task could be solved by MSBuild/Visual Studio without much scripting.